# Exact match in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I have downloaded a custom visual in power bi for text search, when searching it shows all results which contains that word. But I need whole word matching record. How to customise that visual. Not use slicer in this case.

Comment: Exact match meaning search string and column value must be same. And search string should not be a substring of any column in the result of power bi table.